# How to find the Longest repeated Substring using Java Sream?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, java-stream, substring

For a school assignment, I have to implement a method that will return the longest repeated substring from a string. But I have to do it by using only the Stream API.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public static String biggestRedundantSubstring(String s) {
    Stream.Builder<String> stringBuilder = Stream.builder();
    while (!Objects.equals(s, "")) {
        stringBuilder.add(s);
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return stringBuilder.build().sorted().reduce("",
            (String biggestRedundantSubstring, String matchingPrefix) ->
                    biggestRedundantSubstring.length() > matchingPrefix.length() ?
                            biggestRedundantSubstring : matchingPrefix,
            (String sub1, String sub2) -> {
                String matchingPrefix = "";
                int limitIndex = Math.max(sub1.length(), sub2.length()) - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < limitIndex; i++) {
                    if (sub1.charAt(i) == sub2.charAt(i)) {
                        matchingPrefix += sub1.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }       
                return matchingPrefix;
            });
}
```

And this is the `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 0) {
        for (String s : args) {
            System.out.println(s + " " + biggestRedundantSubstring(s));
        }
    } else {
        String s = "ababaac";
        System.out.println(s + " " + biggestRedundantSubstring(s));
    }
}
```

This without arguments should print on console:

```
ababaac aba
```

But instead it prints:

```
ababaac ababaac
```

So I was wondering if it is possible? I also tried to use `reduce()` with three parameters, but it doesn't work either, and I could use a variable outside of the stream to keep track of and change the value of the "biggestRedundantSubstring" variable, but it kind of goes against why to use streams, doesn't it?

Comment: `aba` only appears once, unless you have a typo and your test phrase is actually "abaabaac" or you're using a different definition of "repeating substring" than the common understanding.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Substring `aba` appears twice : `"ababaac".substring(0, 3)` and `"ababaac".substring(2, 5)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, let's describe the *overall algorithm*:

- We need to generate all possible *substrings*. I.e. for every valid index of the string from `0` up to `str.length() - 1` we have to construct all *substrings* having the length from `1` to `str.length() - index`.
- Then we need to check which of these *substrings* occur more than once and pick the longest of them.

To generate all substring, we need to walk through all the valid indices using nested `IntStream` (the same can be done using a nested `for` loop). And when we have all the possible *starting* and *ending* indices, we can turn them into *substrings*.

Then to find out which of these substrings appear more than once, we can use a map `Map<String,Boolean>`, in which *keys* would be the strings itself and a *value* mapped to each *key* would signify whether it's repeated or not. We can do this by using *collector* [`toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

Then when we need to create a stream over the entries of the auxiliary map. Filter out repeated entries and pick the one that has the highest length by using `max()` operation that returns an Optional object and expects a `Comparator` as an argument.

That's how it might look like:

```
public static String biggestRedundantSubstring(String str) {
    
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length()) // generating starting indices
        .boxed()
        .flatMap(start -> IntStream.rangeClosed(start + 1, str.length()).mapToObj(end -> str.substring(start,  end))) // generating ending indices and turning each combination of `start` and `end` into a substring
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(   // creating an intermediate map Map<String, Boolean>
            Function.identity(),
            s -> false,              // is repeated substring = false, because element has been encountered for the first time
            (v1, v2) -> true         // substring has been encountered more than once, i.e. is proved to be repeated
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(Map.Entry::getValue) // filtering the repeated substrings
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))) // returns Optional<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)      // returns Optional<String>
        .orElse("");                 // if Optional is empty return an empty string
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "ababaac";
    System.out.println(s + " " + biggestRedundantSubstring(s));
}
```

*Output:*

```
ababaac aba
```